# how to use two datasets in flink in the same filter function

Tags: dataset, filtering, apache-flink

i am working with two different [Flink 1.1.2]-datasets of different sizes, lets call dem DS_little and DS_Big. what i want to do now is to only keep the entries of DS_Big that have a corresponding entry in DS_little.

something like:

```
if (first element of DS_Big = any element of DS_little)
{keep it and add an additional entry of DS_little to DS_Big}
else{forget it}
```

is there a clever way to do such?

thanks in advance for any potential help,

best t.

Comment: you may want to look into outer joins, although I'm not sure if they are available in 1.1.2. They allow you to find matches between 2 datasets.

Comment: thanks - i appreciate the reference.

ill check it out